# What are the maven dependencies for running Hibernate 5 with MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

I am trying to find the maven dependencies required to successfully run a Hibernate 5 application with MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following dependancies needs to be added to successfully run Hibernate 5 with mySQL database.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maven Dependencies for **Hibernate5** and for **mysql connector**:

```
<!-- Hibernate5 dependecy-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- MySQL database driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.37</version>
</dependency>
```